# Does a field extension equal $F(\alpha) = a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2+a_3\alpha^3+\cdots$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field, does $F(\alpha)=a_0+a_1\alpha+a_2\alpha^2+a_3\alpha^3+\cdots$?

If it does, this was never explicitly stated, and I have gained confusion from this, since in the case that:

$$(*)\quad\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt2:a,b\in \Bbb Q\}$$

I never thought about the fact that $a_0+a_1\sqrt{2}+2a_2+2\sqrt{2}a_3+4a_4+\cdots$ falls into the form written in $(*)$, so I don't really know what this is meant to look like :\

---

If so, then what does $F(\alpha,\beta)$ look like?

Comment: I had many of the same questions when I first looked at this material, for the record, I think these questions are the right ones to be starting on... keep it up.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Thanks for saying that, I appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is an element of a field containing $F$, the definition of $F(\alpha)$ is this:
$$F(\alpha)=\biggl\{\dfrac{P(\alpha)}{Q(\alpha)}\;\bigg\vert\; P(X), Q(X)\in F[X]\enspace\text{and}\enspace Q(\alpha)\neq 0\biggr\}.$$
If $\alpha$  is transcendental over $F$, there is nothing more to say. If  $\alpha$  is algebraic over $F$, say $\alpha$ satisfies an lagebraic equation of degree $d$, an easy induction shows the polynomials $P$ and $Q$ may be taken with degree $<n$.

For two elements, the definition is similar, but with polynomials in two indeterminates:
$$F(\alpha, \beta)=\biggl\{\dfrac{P(\alpha, \beta)}{Q(\alpha, \beta)}\;\bigg\vert\; P(X, Y), Q(X, Y)\in F[X, Y]\enspace\text{and}\enspace Q(\alpha, \beta)\neq 0\biggr\}.$$

Comment: I guess he asked about 3 questions here, between our answers I think we got them all.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Sorry about the 3 questions thing, just reading both answers atm

Comment: @GaloisintheField no problem, you should probably accept Bernard's since his has more depth to it.

Comment: Sorry, "If $\alpha$ is an element of a field 'containing' $F$" is that written right? So we have $F(\alpha)$ is the field $F$ adjoining the root $\alpha$ and this equals a fraction field of all polynomials evaluated at $\alpha$ in the polynomial ring $F[x]$ (where the denominator is nonzero)

Comment: Yes, I mean an overfield of $F$ (like $\mathbf Q$  and $\mathbf C$).

Comment: @James S. Cook: It's  a nebula of questions, that are more or less related, and anyway linked, to the eyes of the O.P.

Comment: I don't mean to be annoying, but I am still having trouble understanding. Is this the same notation as when we look at the gaussian integers? $\Bbb Z(i)$? I am not sure if maybe we are using different notation

Comment: You're not annoying at all. It is the same notation, except Gaussian integers are $\mathbf Z[i]$, really. Their field of fractions are *Gaussian numbers*, $\mathbf Q(i)$.

Answer (score 2):

First, $\mathbb{F}(\alpha)$ is a **set**. Be careful to distinguish between the elements in the set and the set itself. Second, the element $a_o+2a_2+4a_4+ \cdots = c_1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ since the sum of rational numbers is rational. Likewise, the terms with $\sqrt{2}$ also group together to give a single term.